# Why does Compiz suddenly stop working?

Tags: 11.10, compiz

I have 11.10 installed and have deactivated the Compiz animated effects, but have turned on wobbly windows. So, in short, windows don't fade / slide / etc, but they wobble.

I can't find a pattern, but it seems that while I am working for a few hours, the wobbly windows suddenly stop being wobbly for no reason. Only on some windows, mind you.

It's obviously not expected behaviour...

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some program/script on your computer changing the current window manager. When the windows don't wobbly anymore, open a terminal and try `compiz --replace`. If that works, you've to find what is changing the window manager and keep it from replacing it.

Comment: What does that command do? Will it make my desktop unusable?

Comment: It restarts compiz. That's all.

Comment: Does it reset's Compiz's settings?

Comment: No, it will just replace the current window manager. It won't do any harm to your desktop. The worst it could happen is you need to restart the computer.